# How do I remove :width and :height from an image created with create-image?

Tags: setf

I am trying to make [jabber.el](http://emacs-jabber.sourceforge.net/) support images sent from e.g. [Conversations](https://conversations.im/).

I download the image using `url-retrieve-synchonously` and call `create-image` to get an image which I can then use with `insert-image`. This works as expected.

I would like, however, to put a `:max-width` and `:max-height` on the image. I can add them in the `create-image` call, but because `create-image` automatically inserts a `:width` and a `:height` image property, the max-values are ignored, as the manual explains:

> The :max-width and :max-height keywords are used for scaling if the size of the image of the image exceeds these values. If :width is set it will have precedence over max-width, and if :height is set it will have precedence over max-height

- https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/ImageMagick-Images.html#ImageMagick-Images

The documentation says that I can remove image properties with `setf`, by setting them to `nil`:

> Function: image-property image property
>
> Return the value of property in image. Properties can be set by using setf. Setting a property to nil will remove the property from the image.

- https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Images.html

This, however, I can't make work - if I `setf` a property to `nil`, the key is deleted, but the value isn't, and the image object seems to be messed up.

Example (simplified):

```
(defun my-fetch-image (url)
  "Retun filename of image downloaded from url"
  (url-copy-file url "/tmp/test.jpg")
  (create-image "/tmp/test.jpg"))

(setq my-image (my-fetch-image "https://koldfront.dk/photo/pics/2018/09/snapshot-22-142810-s.jpg"))
```

Now, my-image looks like this: `(image :type imagemagick :file "/tmp/test.jpg" :scale 1.2019047619047618 :width 288 :height 400)`

And when I try to remove width and height:

```
(setf (image-property my-image :width) nil)
(setf (image-property my-image :height) nil)
```

I am left with my-image looking like this: `(image :type imagemagick :file "/tmp/test.jpg" :scale 1.2019047619047618 288 :height 400)`

As you can see `:width` got removed, but the value `288` is still there, and `:height 400` is untouched.

I'm sure I haven't understood how to use `setf`, but I can't find any examples to go by, and my guesses don't yield the result I'm after, either.

Comment: I am using GNU Emacs 26.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Update***: The following statement is incorrect, I can reproduce the issue, and I believe it's a bug of `image--set-property`.

I can't reproduce with Emacs 26.1 and 26.2 from `emacs -Q`, the following produces the expected result, unlike yours:

```el
;; So `setf' can know how to macroexpand `image-property'
(require 'image)

(let ((my-image '(image :type imagemagick
                        :file "/tmp/test.jpg"
                        :scale 1.2019047619047618
                        :width 288
                        :height 400)))
  (setf (image-property my-image :width) nil)
  my-image)

;; =>

(image :type imagemagick
       :file "/tmp/test.jpg"
       :scale 1.2019047619047618 288
       :height 400)
```

`setf` is a macro, so you can macroexpand it to understand what's it doing, for example, `(setf (point) 1)` expands to `(goto-char 1)`. (Personally, I use `M-x macrostep-expand` from a third-party package, however, nowadays Emacs provides the builtin `emacs-lisp-macroexpand` command.).

Comment: Uhm, the result you show is the same result as I get. Notice the "288" efter the floating point value in your output? That's the value of the :width your call to setf removed.

Comment: If you add another setf call to remove the :height, I bet it won't be gone for you either.

Comment: @asjo Oops, you're right, I missed the number 288. There is a bug in `image--set-property`, `(setcdr image (cddr image))` should be `(setcdr image (cdddr image))`, i.e., change `cddr` into `cdddr`.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it - have you reported the bug or should I?

Comment: @asjo No, I've not. I think you should.

Comment: Thanks for the help analyzing this, I have reported the bug now: https://debbugs.gnu.org/35285

Answer (score 0):

So far, the workaround I have found is:

```
            (let ((width (image-property image :width))
                  (height (image-property image :height)))
              (setf (image-property image :width) nil)
              (setf (image-property image width) nil)
              (setf (image-property image :height) nil)
              (setf (image-property image height) nil))
```

This can't be the right way‽

Answer (score 0):

For what's worth, since it's bug of Emacs, before it gets fixed, you can roll your own, something like the following (I wrote it mainly for fun and some practice):

```el
(defun my-image-delete-properties (image &rest props)
  (cl-loop for (k v) on (cdr image) by #'cddr
           unless (memq k props)
           nconc (list k v) into properties
           finally return (cons (car image) properties)))

(let ((my-image '(image :type imagemagick
                        :file "/tmp/test.jpg"
                        :scale 1.2019047619047618
                        :width 288
                        :height 400)))
  (my-image-delete-properties my-image :width :height))
;; => (image :type imagemagick
;;           :file "/tmp/test.jpg"
;;           :scale 1.2019047619047618)
```

Unlike `(setf (image-property image :width) nil)`, the above doesn't change `image` in-place (it is usually a good idea), if you want that, you can try the following instead:

```el
(defun my-image-delete-properties (image &rest props)
  (cl-loop for (k v) on (cdr image) by #'cddr
           unless (memq k props)
           nconc (list k v) into properties
           finally return (setcdr image properties))
  image)

(let ((my-image '(image :type imagemagick
                        :file "/tmp/test.jpg"
                        :scale 1.2019047619047618
                        :width 288
                        :height 400)))
  (my-image-delete-properties my-image :width :height)
  my-image)
;; => (image :type imagemagick
;;           :file "/tmp/test.jpg"
;;           :scale 1.2019047619047618)
```

By the way, there is `org-plist-delete` for deleting a property from a plist, it doesn't change the argument in-place as well, like the first `my-image-delete-properties`.